# Remoting from a Swing app to GWT server

Tags: java, swing, gwt, remoting, restlet

To put it simple, I've written a JSE Swing app that needs to talk to a GWT server I've written earlier.
I absolutely love the way GWT does remoting between it's javascript and server sides and wish I could utilize this mechanism.
Has anyone managed to use GWT-RPC this way? Should I just go Restlet instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing Java-to-Java communication, RMI would be simpler and more expedient.  Serializing data to/from some XML or  URL-based format doesn't add a lot of value.

With EJB3, it is dead simple to deploy remote objects and to call them.  You can then turn those EJBs into web services if you need to later, but for Java-to-Java, I can't think of a good reason to *not* use some sort of RMI-based communication.

Comment: RMI does not work at the moment on AppEngine. I'm not sure if Google will fix that